# How can i loop trough nested objects and validate some calculations with lambda and streams

Tags: java, oop, lambda, java-stream

I need to loop trough nested objects validating some calculations. ex:

```
Category obj1 = new Category(0, 0, 10, null);
Category obj2 = new Category(2, 3, 6, obj1);
Category obj3 = new Category(2, 2, 4, obj1);
```

And i need to check if a parent exists following :
sum2(qty * price = total)
sum3(qty * price = total)   and sum2+sum3== parent total

ex:
(2*2==4) 
(3*3==6)   and 4+6 == 10

How can i do that with lambda and streams?

```
public class Category {

    private int qty;
    private int price;

    private int total;

    private Category rootCategory;

}
```

Comment: Please provide the code using traditional loops at least.

Comment: A util helpful there could be `boolean validateTotal(Category parent, Set<Category> children) {
        return parent.getTotal() == children.stream().mapToLong(child -> child.getPrice() * child.getQty()).sum();
    }`. In order to make use of it, one can think of ways of passing the parents and their children to validate their total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Stream.of` to create `Category` stream and then `filter` objects with `rootCategory` is not null

```
int sum = Stream.of(obj1, obj2, obj3)
        .filter(o -> Objects.nonNull(o.getRootCategory()))
        .mapToInt(c -> c.getQty() * c.getPrice())
        .sum();
```

Comment: let's say that there are many categories  having same root, 10 ,20 , i think it should loop trough all categs that have same root.

Comment: what do you mean by same root? what is `10` and `20`? @Black.us

Comment: childCategories having same root